# setter methods and Restricted Python

Tags: python, setter, zope, restrictedpython

I have a class "MyClass" with a class attribute and its methods.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_attr = None

    @property
    def my_attr(self):
        return self._my_attr

    @my_attr.setter
    def my_attr(self, value):
        self._my_attr = value

    def set_my_attr(self, value):
        self._my_attr = value
```

When I try to assign a value in Zope (in a Python Script, which uses Restricted Python), I get a TypeError `attribute-less object (assign or del)` when I try to assign the value with `=`.

It also says in the traceback: `AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__guarded_setattr__'`

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.my_attr = 42  # error in Restricted Python
obj.set_my_attr(value=42)  # does work in Restricted Python
```

What does the error mean? Is there a way to allow setter methods for direct assignment in Restricted Python or do I have to implement a normal method to set the value?

Comment: Side note: why do you have a `set_my_attr()` in addition to a proper setter? Just for the example?

Comment: I found the documentation a bit hard to follow, but what kind of guard are you using? https://restrictedpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/policy.html#guards The "attribute-less object" message seems expected for certain guards: https://restrictedpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/policy.html#guards-1

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні the `set_my_attr()` method is there as an alternative that's working in Restricted Python, that's its sole purpose.

Comment: @slothrop As I use Zope which in turn uses Restricted Python for its "Python Scripts" in the ZODB, I have not configured Restricted Python myself, so I don't know which guard is used. I also would be curious if the Restricted Python settings can be changed for a Zope instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the the check if you set the following flag:

```py
class MyClass:
    _guarded_writes = 1
```

Usually code gets wrapped with...:

```
    class Wrapper:
        def __init__(self, ob):
            self.__dict__['ob'] = ob

        __setitem__ = _handler(
            '__guarded_setitem__',
            'object does not support item or slice assignment')

        __delitem__ = _handler(
            '__guarded_delitem__',
            'object does not support item or slice assignment')

        __setattr__ = _handler(
            '__guarded_setattr__',
            'attribute-less object (assign or del)')

        __delattr__ = _handler(
            '__guarded_delattr__',
            'attribute-less object (assign or del)')
    return Wrapper
```

which disallows setting anything.